# appending a arrays of a list into arrays of another list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have two lists that each one includes arrays. I want to append arrays of one list at the end of arrays of another one. I mean:

```
inp1 = [np.array([[2.5, 1.5, 0.]]),
        np.array([[3., 2., 0.], [2.1, 2., -1.]])]

inp2 = [np.array([[10., 20., 30.]]),
        np.array([[100., 100., 100.], [200., 200., 400.]])]
```

Then, I want to append first array of `inp2` at the end of first array of `inp1`. Then, second of `inp2` at the ned of second of `inp1` and so on. I want to have the results as following:

```
outp= [np.array([[2.5, 1.5, 0.],
                 [10., 20., 30.]]),
       np.array([[3., 2., 0.],
                 [2.1, 2., -1.],
                 [100., 100., 100.],
                 [200., 200., 400.]])]
```

I tried the following but it gave me another result:

```
outp1=zip(inp1, inp2)
outp1=list(outp1)
```

In reality I have hundreds of arrays stored in `inp1` and `inp2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this :

```
l = [np.append(array, to_append, axis=0) for (array, to_append) in zip(inp1, inp2)]
print(l)
```

Comment: Dear @tgrandje, Thanks a lot. Thats exactly what I needed.